# Error while counting number of entries in a Mongo database using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to access my MongoDB database with pymongo in Python 2.7. Unfortunately, when I try to count the number of times a key/value pair appears in my database I get an error. If I concatenate all my function calls together, the following line of code is how I am counting the number of times the object appears.

```
MongoClient(<My Mongo Connection>).get_default_database(['media'].find("media_url":data["media_url"]).count()
```

Part of the corresponding error is as follows:

```
  File "<File Path Removed for Privacy>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 97, in select_servers
self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members found yet
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it? I have made sure that my MongoDB connection string is correct. I am a newbie with MongoDB and interfacing it with Flask applications, so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: your mongo connection failed, do you have replica sets?

Comment: I have nothing in my database currently. I have two servers accessing my database. Is this the information you were looking for? I tried to give the proper information via [Mongo's replication documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/).

Comment: which version of pymongo? how many mongodb instances you've, one or more?

Comment: I am using version 3.0.2. I have one mongodb instance.

Comment: check this (https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/413), it states you should update your pymongo to 3.4+. if that's not the case then make sure `MongoClient(<My Mongo Connection>)` is correct.

Comment: When I do that I then get the error: `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed`

Comment: you updated the pymongo?

Comment: Yes, I did update pymongo to 3.5.

Comment: this looks like it's not able to establish connection. you'll have to check your connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to pymongo 3.5.1, changed the password to my database, and recopied my connection string. That did the trick and fixed all errors!